# Ising simulation-dimensionless

Tags: simulations, spacetime-dimensions, ising-model

My question is about dimensions in Ising model.When we want to simulate Ising we use dimensionless parameter as you know.We choose J to be 1 and also K equal 1 and when temperature is 2.26 then it's our critical point.My questions is how can we turn our dimensionless temperature to the real one.I searched a lot to find out J's SI value but I couldn't.

Comment: The $\sigma$ spin states are dimensionless so the $J$'s must have the same dimension as the Hamiltonian (i.e. energy). I'm not sure what you're referring to with the $K$ though...

Comment: It's Boltzman constant see below answer @lemon

Answer (score 2):

The critical point of the Ising model in two dimensions is about
$$ T= 2.269 \frac{J}{k_B},$$

where $J$ is a free parameter that can be interpred as the coupling between spins and has energy units. So by introducing $J$ (experimentally or by other calculation) and dividing by $k_B$ (Boltzmann's constant) you would get the temperature in Kelvin.

Comment: yes you are completely right,I was wondering if you know the J experimental value? @jinawee

Comment: @jack It depends entirely on the material. Some experimental comparisons can be found [here](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-97332000000400030)